# In SVN after committing the changes by user not redirect in directory

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, httpd, repository

I configured SVN on a Server having OS CentOS 6.4 as follows:

```
# yum install mod_dav_svn subversion -y 

# vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf 

<Location /svn>
   DAV svn 
   SVNParentPath /var/www/svn 
      AuthType Basic 
      AuthName "subversion repositories"
      AuthUserFile /etc/svn-users
      Require valid-user
</Location>

# mkdir /var/www/svn
# cd /var/www/svn
# svnadmin create myproject
# chown -R apache.apache myproject
# svn co http://ip.add.re.ss/svn/myrepo/
# cd myproject
# touch file1.txt file2.txt
# svn add file1.txt file2.txt
# svn ci file1.txt file2.txt -m “initial commit
```

Later I provided the directories to users.  After users modified some files in the directories the changes are committed and updated properly.  When I view files in a browser, e.g.: `http://ip.add/svn/myproject/file1.txt`
the changes are properly seen.  However when I go to directory itself in `/var/www/svn/myproject/file1.txt` the file is shown blank.

How i can resolve this problem?

Comment: Dod you check out to `/var/www/svn/myproject` (or rather, run `svn update` in) after the updates were committed?

Comment: Yes, nothing is reflected in directory file and i did svn update  says Skipped.

Comment: Please update the question with the output of running `svn update` in the `/var/www/svn/myproject` directory.